# Show that, if a map $f: X \to Y$ is nullhomotopic then it extends to a map $f_*$ from the cone $CX$ to Y.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, solution-verification, quotient-spaces

Below I specify a definition of $f_*$, and would like to **directly** check for its continuity. Please give your opinion on whether the proof is valid.

Let $c$ be a constant map from $X$ to $Y$ that maps $x$ to $c(x) = y$. Since $f \simeq c$, there exists a mapping $F: X \times I \to Y$ such that $F(x,0) = f(x)$ and $F(x,1) = c(x) = y$.

Now use the definition of $CX = ((X \times I)/ \sim) = (X \times [0,1)) \cup \{p\}$, where $(x_1,1) \sim(x_2,1) \ \forall x_1,x_2 \in X$, and $p$ is a point. Then define $f_*$ as:
$$
\begin{cases}
f_*(x,t) = F(x,t)  & x \in X, 0 \leq t < 1 \\
f_*(\ p \ ) = F(x,1) = y
\end{cases}$$

Let $U \subset Y$ be open. Since $F$ is continuous, $f_*^{-1}(U) = F^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X \times I$. Is it a valid assertion that $f_*^{-1}(U)$ is hence open in the quotient space $CX$?

Comment: @NoelLundström Write it up as an answer, you'll get more credit that way.

Comment: Thanks for your post, Do you know the vise versa proof? when we have the extension and we want to show that f: X->Y is nullhomotopic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all $f_* ^{-1}(U) = F^{-1}(U)$ is not true since these maps don't even have the same domain.

You have the projection map $\pi : X \times I \rightarrow CX$ and it's easy to check that $f_* \circ \pi = F$, thus we must have $\pi^{-1}(f_*^{-1}(U)) = F^{-1}(U)$.

We also know that a subset of $CX$ is open if and only if its preimage under $\pi$ is open. Thus since $F^{-1}(U)$ is open $f_*^{-1}(U)$ must also be open by definition of quotient topology, so $f_*$ is continuous.